# How to use rangebreaks from plotly?

Tags: python, plotly

I would like to remove certain intervals from my xaxis in some plots using plotly. I found the attached example from https://plotly.com/python/time-series/. But running it gives me the error

> ValueError: Invalid property specified for object of type
>   plotly.graph_objs.layout.XAxis: 'rangebreaks'

I even upgraded my plotly-version. How can I use the rangebreaks property?

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/finance-charts-apple.csv')

fig = px.scatter(df, x='Date', y='AAPL.High', range_x=['2015-12-01', '2016-01-15'],
                 title="Hide Gaps with rangebreaks")
fig.update_xaxes(
    rangebreaks=[
        dict(bounds=["sat", "mon"]), #hide weekends
        dict(values=["2015-12-25", "2016-01-01"])  # hide Christmas and New Year's
    ]
)
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are running the latest version of plotly this should work, maybe try to restart the kernel

and 
check if you have these files in your system:
...\Lib\site-packages\plotly\validators\layout\yaxis_rangebreaks.py
..\Lib\site-packages\plotly\validators\layout\xaxis_rangebreaks.py

Answer (score 0):

I am running colab and this worked for me:

```
!pip install --upgrade dash
```

Followed by restarting the kernel (or just run the update when you are first importing and installing packages).

Not really sure what's going on, but found the answer [here](https://github.com/plotly/dash/issues/1196).